# AngularJS formatting input value to currency and comma separated number if it's only number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angularjs single page application. In the form, there are several input fields controls which can have either any text values e.g. ($12,345 NEDRO) or it can have only amount(e.g. $1,234,567.25). Now if it's only amount then I would like to format to proper currency (which is only $), with commas if user just inputs the number which can be integer or decimal. For example, if user enters 100000, it should be automatically converted to $100,000 either when user leaves the input field or while typing. If user enters the number with proper format e.g. $123,456.34, then no changes required.

What's the best way to handle it? And can someone please provide the code for it.